Pumping Lemma for for Context Free Languages Example
Let Σ = {, } and
 = { ∈ Σ∗
∣ for all nonempty  ∈ Σ∗
, the string  does not occur in }.
The language  is infinite. Using this fact and the pumping lemma for context free languages, prove that  is not context-free.
I am told that the key to this question is that the language L is infinite but why can that be used to prove that its not context-free?

What are the pumping lemmata all about?

We need infinity here because if $L$ were a finite language, it would be regular, which means it would be context-free. (All finite languages are regular.)
You’ll want to do a proof by contradiction: assume $L$ is context-free. The pumping lemma gives us a length $p$ after which all strings can be pumped. Since $L$ is infinite, $L$ contains some string $x$ of length at least $p$. If you show that $x$ can be pumped into a string $x'\in L$ containing a substring $sss$ for a nonempty $s\in \Sigma^*$, then you're done.

Welcome to CS@SE. Well done for not ruining a learning experience.

I did know the first part but wasn't sure if that is why infinity mattered, thank you for the clarification! I just want to clarify the second part as well I did have the idea of showing any x of length at least p for some pumping length p can be pumped into x', is this the correct approach? x when decomposed into uvxyz and pumped for an i > 2 e.g uvvvxyyyyz will be pumped outside of the language as it will contain sss as yyy and vvv are naturally ∈Σ* hence there is an s equal to v or y?

@idk What if v is empty? What if y is empty?

@wobtax From my understanding only one can be empty at a time as |vy| > 0 so if y is empty won't v still get pumped up and become vvv = sss and vice versa?

@idk It sounds like you're on the right track!
